# Why am I getting "command not found" after typing "npm install" on my Mac?

Tags: npm, installation, terminal, package

I am very new to programming, so sorry if this is very stupid question.

I am using terminal (both Warp and the regular terminal) and typing "npm install" on my Mac laptop.
I am getting "zsh: command not found: npm".

What could be the problem and how to solve?
I appreciate any advice, or even more general learning sources for this topic.
Thank you!

I tried command npm - install to install required packages for a ChatGPT plugin.
I got an error message "zsh: command not found: npm".

Comment: You either don't have npm installed or it isn't in your PATH variable